# itemprop in sharepoint 2013

Tags: html, asp.net, sharepoint

The site runs on the sharepoint 2013 platform. I need to tag itemprop micro-tags on the information pages of the educational organization.

If I do this in sharepoint designer, when I save, it deletes "unsafe content" [(Here's a warning before saving)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qppz7.jpg). 
I think you can solve the problem by disabling or updating the compatibility check, because now sharepoint designer makes sure that everything is compatible with IE 6.0 [(Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnsCZ.jpg). But I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What file are you saving your changes into? Your changes aren't being removed because of compatibility, it'll be for another reason.

Comment: I am saving aspx file.

Comment: @Egor which aspx file exactly? a page layout, display template, master page, custom page etc

Comment: custom page. Itemprop should only be placed in the content area if it matters.